# How to get Cython to switch a compiler?

Tags: python, c, cython, cythonize

So basically, I want Cython to use GCC/G++, but it says that I must download Visual Studio 14.0, which is useless,
making it a bloatware.

Last time I asked (at GitHub), people suggested me to download Visual Studio 2015. And if you want to download it, you must be subscribed. And that did not help me.
So how do I force Cython to use GCC/G++?

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='Hello world app',
    ext_modules=cythonize("hello.pyx"),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Comment: distutils doesn't support other compilers than MSVC on windows. Hacks is all is left.

Comment: @ead, I got to install MSVC, but how do I make it detect MSVC?